# Не подскажите, как в Python 3 из списка (массива) узнать все числа, которые начинаются, например, с 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример списка (массива):

```
s = [456,456,6578,124,38456,8567,78,4562,65,435,7845,13,2,35,3865,
     23458,2,1325,11413,754,2345,89763,155432,753]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = [-321, # проверяем работу с отрицательными числами
     456,456,6578,124,38456,8567,78,4562,65,435,7845,13,2,35,
     3865,2,1325,11413,754,2345,89763,155432,753]
```

Один из вариантов - проверить начинается ли *строковое* представление модуля числа с `'3'`:

```
res = [x for x in s if str(abs(x)).startswith('3')]
print(res)
#[-321, 38456, 35, 3865]
```

[Вариант без использования строк](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716024/5741205):

```
import math

res = [num for num in s if abs(num) // 10 ** (int(math.log(abs(num), 10))) == 3]
print(res)
#[-321, 38456, 35, 3865]
```

Comment: Насколько я понял первый способ в программе выглядит как-от так: for x in s:
    x = str(x)
    if x.startswiht('3'):
      print (x)

Comment: @Алексей, это зависит от определения глагола "узнать" в вашем вопросе ;) Узнать - это получить новый список или вывести на экран?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточность, мне нужен новый список.

Comment: @Алексей, исправил ответ. `res` - новый список

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручили.